# Getting value from another table through id

Tags: database, laravel

I am new to laravel. I have a table:

> **students_attendance**.

In `students_attendance` I have a column named `class_id`, which refers to the `students_classes` table that also includes the `class_id` and `class_name` for each student.

In the frontend table I am getting the values from `students_attendance` table so the `class_id` is available, but what I need is the `class_name`.

How I can get the `class_name`?

//Migration for students_attendance

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students_attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('class_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('student_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('attendance');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

//Migration for students_classes

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students_classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('class_name');
            $table->string('class_fee');
            $table->string('class_teacher');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

//Students Class Model

```
class StudentsClass extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'class_name',
        'class_fee',
        'class_teacher'
    ];

    public function students() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Students');
    }

}
```

//Students Attendance Model

```
class StudentsAttendance extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'class_id',
        'student_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'attendance'
    ];

    public function studentsClass() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\StudentsClass');
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use relation between this tables...please show your migrations

Comment: you want to get the class_name using students_attendance.id do you mean?? or using students_attendance_register.id?? please elaborate your question

Comment: can you show also your migration/database structure & your actual querying..

Comment: Pls check the updated question. These two are my migrations

Comment: migrations dn't help. Show us your model associations

Comment: Check again pls

Comment: It's not clear what `students_attendance_register` is

Comment: students attendance register is just my front page table name. It does not have any table in the database but it will get the attendance from the i have in database named as students_attendance

Answer (score 0):

From a `StatusAttendance` variable you can access the class name with `$attendance->studentClass->class_name`.

Assuming you have the `class_id` and you want to get the name of the associated class, you can simply do this:

```
$class = StudentsClass::find($class_id);
$class->class_name; // Outputs the name
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'class_name' of non-object

Comment: It means there are no classes with the id stored in `$class_id`.

Comment: Here is classes with the id stored in $class_id